# svn:bugtraq pointing at multiple JIRA databases

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

Is there any way without writing an IBugtraqProvider to direct Subversion clients to two different JIRA databases depending on the format of the issue number in the log message?

Background:

For security reasons we have multiple JIRA databases where the tickets for the projects are stored - let's call them jira.acme.com and internaljira.acme.com .  Sometimes tickets from both different JIRA instances can apply to the same project.

Tickets have different JIRA prefixes in the different databases - let's say FOO-nnn corresponding to https://jira.acme.com:9876/browse/FOO-nnn and BAR-nnn corresponding to https://internaljira.acme.com:7437/browse/BAR-nnn .

Is there any way to set up the svn:bugtraq properties so that FOO-123 will link to https://jira.acme.com:9876/browse/FOO-123 and BAR-456 will link to https://internaljira.acme.com:7437/browse/BAR-456 ?

I've been scratching my head and I haven't been able to work out how to vary the URL based on the format of the detected issue number, but I don't want to have to write and deploy an IBugtraqProvider DLL for everyone in the company who needs to access these.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Ian